# How close is cdebconf able to serve as a drop-in replacement for debconf?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package-management, software-installation

Most of the internet information around cdebconf is circa 06`, or I was just unable to find its location.  Please mention if recent documentation, or FAQ, is available.

Is cdebconf able to serve as a drop-in replacement for debconf?  As of 06` it apparently was not, but it's been about 6 years from that time.  I would assume the status has changes since then, but by how much?

**NOTE:** Please refrain from answering these questions, plenty of available grounded opinions exist.

1. Why the community needs cdebconf?
2. Why debconf needs a replacement?

Comment: (I cannot answer your question, but) [according to the source](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=d-i/cdebconf.git;a=summary) it's still actively developed; there's also a  [`TODO`](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=d-i/cdebconf.git;a=blob;f=doc/TODO;h=06cee6a75698d74a3857042960cb3914ded554d9;hb=HEAD).

Comment: IMO debian-devel@lists.debian.org is a much more suitable place for those questions. EDIT: There is also deity@lists.debian.org which is the list dpkg developers watch.

Comment: I posted a question on the lists, hopefully it will get answered. I'll update status when appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I messaged the lists, they said I should test it out.  Improvements have brought the progress much closer to drop-in functionality.   Hopefully we get cdebconf as a full replacement one day.